# What's the best hashing algorithm when using a smaller user database

Tags: algorithm, security, hash, passwords

When it comes to hashing passwords the best algorithms are slower ones, Argon2 and bcrypt to name a few.  However if you have a small user base, say around 10,000 users, are slower algorithms still the best solution?

Comment: Yes. It's not a decision driven much by the number of users. Keepass, which stores personal passwords for one user also stick to those slow methods.

Comment: I thought Keepsake is more a end user solution for storing their passwords vs website security

Comment: It's different, but the reasoning is the same. Don't allow fast brute-forcing.

Comment: I really have not heard of using Keepass for this purpose.  Do you have any links that I can read up on for website security with this approach?

Comment: I did not say it's for that purpose. I only showed some example where there is only one user and you still want very slow key derivation.

Comment: You might get better answers on [SecuritySE](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Nevertheless, the size of the user-base doesn't change much about which algorithms to use.

Comment: Your right, that might have been a better option initially.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see John Steven's [Secure Password Storage Threat Model](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1R6c9NW6wtoEoT3CS4UVmthw1a6Ex6TGSBaEqDay5U7g). I've never seen a model affected by user database size. Can you detail your concerns over a small user database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no argument **against** using best practise with smaller databases. The work, whether you call BCrypt or SHA-* is  the same, maybe even smaller with BCrypt because the salt handling and storage is done for you.

Btw this would not be the first database/code designed for a small audience, but growing/reused for a much larger project.

Comment: Thank you.  I will always use best practices but was wondering if there was a different best practice for smaller databases that have a high probability of not growing too large.

Comment: @Michael - There should be really no difference in handling, as said it will probably even be easier using the BCrypt/SCrypt/Argon2, because they include the salt in the resulting hash-string, so you need only a single db field to store the password hashes.